# starting BroadcastReceiver or IntentService from non-activity class

Tags: android, class, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

How to start BroadcastReceiver or IntentService from **non-activity** class

by start I mean send intent and make run BroadcastService or IntentService

I.e:

I have class:

```
public class NumberOne{
     @Override
     public int functionOne(){
       int i = 1 + 4;

        if(/*something is true*/){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,intetServiceOne.class);
        intent.putExtra("id","path");
        context.startService(intent);
      }
      else {/*continue*/
      }
        return i;  
      }
       //other functions
     }
```

and if a condition in functionOne is true start IntentService

```
public class IntentServiceClassOne extends IntentService {
     public IntentServiceClassOne () {
        super("IntentServiceClassOne ");
     }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        Log.d("dataIs: ", data);
    }
    //more functions what to do
    }
```

It dont depend if it is IntentService or BroadcastReceiver
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start service You need context instance. You can pass it as  constructor parameter:

```
public class NumberOne{
     Context context;

     public NumberOne(Context context){
         this.context = context;
     }
     public int functionOne(Context context){
       int i = 1 + 4;

        if(/*something is true*/){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,intetServiceOne.class);
           intent.putExtra("id","path");
           context.startService(intent);
        }
        else {/*continue*/
        }
        return i;  
    }
    //other functions
}
```

You don't have to pass Activity instance, Context is enough. It can be application context. You can get it by `getApplicationContext()` method

You can also create static instance in Application object and get it from them:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    public static YourApplication INSTANCE;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        INSTANCE = this;
    }
}
```

And your class will be look like below.

```
public class NumberOne{

     public int functionOne(Context context){
       int i = 1 + 4;

        if(/*something is true*/){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,intetServiceOne.class);
           intent.putExtra("id","path");
           YourApplication.INSTANCE.startService(intent);
        }
        else {/*continue*/
        }
        return i;  
    }
    //other functions
}
```

But is not good solution.

And the last you can create callback listener and set it in your class like below:

```
public class NumberOne{
     //add setter
     YourListener yourListener;
     public int functionOne(Context context){
       int i = 1 + 4;

        if(/*something is true*/){
           if(yourListener != null){
               yourListener.onFunctionOneCall();
           }
        }
        else {/*continue*/
        }
        return i;  
    }
    //other functions

    public interface YourListener{
        void onFunctionOneCall();
    }
}
```

And some place where you have context - for example in activity:

```
numberOneInstance.setYourListener(new YourListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFunctionOneCall(){
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,intetServiceOne.class);
               intent.putExtra("id","path");
               this.startService(intent);
    }
});
```

or you can set context by setter

```
public class NumberOne{
     Context context;

     public setContext(Context context){
         this.context = context;
     }
     public int functionOne(Context context){
       int i = 1 + 4;

        if(/*something is true*/){
           if(context != null){
              Intent intent = new Intent(this,intetServiceOne.class);
              intent.putExtra("id","path");
              context.startService(intent);
           }
        }
        else {/*continue*/
        }
        return i;  
    }
    //other functions
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to say that functionOne is @Override, so I cant add another parameters

Comment: So the first solution is wrong - you have to use second solution

Comment: It is all solution which I know :)

Comment: Maybe I dont understand, but as I said `public int functionOne()` is `@Override`, and when I change it to `public int functionOne(Context context)`, it will be no longer `@Override`

Comment: You can not do this if this function is override you can not add new params

Comment: I removed my first solution it was my mistake

Comment: There is no way to start service activity or send intent without context. You need it.

Comment: Did you try some of my solutions?

Comment: I have tried them, but It will not work, so I will try to make some broadcast for it, thanks anyway for trying, at least now I fully understand it.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?